# Mysql, data spread over two tables, seperate rows

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have data spread over two MySQL tables with different structures.

One table has DVDs and the other has CDs.

The DVD table is as follow:

```
PUBLISHER
STOCK
DVD_INFO
EXTRA_DVD_INFO
```

The CDs table is as follow:

```
PUBLISHER
STOCK
CD_INFO
```

How do you get all the CDs and DVDs by the same publisher in one query, ordered by `STOCK`?

- One row per product.
- If it's a CD, then the DVD specific fields should be empty.
- If it's a DVD, then the CD specific fields should be empty.

I don't think `UNION` can work because the structures are different.

I'm not sure how `JOIN` could work in this case to get separate rows for each product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NULL's to fill in the empty columns, eg.

```
SELECT
    PUBLISHER,
    STOCK,
    DVD_INFO AS INFO,
    EXTRA_DVD_INFO
FROM DVD
WHERE PUBLISHER = ?
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    PUBLISHER,
    STOCK,
    CD_INFO AS INFO,
    NULL
FROM CD
WHERE PUBLISHER = ?
ORDER BY STOCK;
```

Comment: also add `WHERE PUBLISHER = "x"` to both queries for filtering by a specific publisher...

Comment: FYI, I think only your second SELECT will be sorted. I could be wrong though (I'd like it to be wrong, actually).

Comment: @MPelletier, it orders the whole set, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know about using NULL as a select. Tweaked it a bit so that DVD_INFO and CD_INFO don't get merged.